# Listen an event when another function of the class is running?

Tags: matlab, oop, events, callback, listener

My class looks like:

```
classdef linescan99 < handle
 methods
        function obj = linescan99(obj_watcher)
           addlistener(obj_watcher,'Contact',@obj.handleEvnt);
        end
        function follower(obj)
            while 1
                %computations
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I've noted that when the follower function is executing, the class is unable to listen a possible event 'Contact'. What's unfortunate: this event would lead to a break of the follower function while 1 loop...

Do you know how to force the function to listen the event? maybe inside the loop?

Thank you very much

........

```
classdef watcher < handle
   properties
       State = false
   end
   events
      Contact
   end
   methods
      function OnStateChange(obj,newState)
         if newState ~= obj.State
            obj.State = newState;
            notify(obj,'Contact');
         end
      end
      function follower(obj)
          while 1
              data=inputSingleScan(sessions_daq.NI_USB_1);
              if data>3
                  obj.OnStateChange(true)
              else
                  obj.OnStateChange(false)
              end
          end
      end
   end
end
```

and

```
classdef linescan99 < handle
    properties
        cam=videoinput('gige');
        %several properties used in the function "follower"...
        State = false
        State2
    end
    methods

        function obj = linescan99(obj_watcher)
           addlistener(obj_watcher,'Contact',@obj.handleEvnt);
        end
        function handleEvnt(obj,obj_watcher,~)
           if obj_watcher.State %contact
              disp('linescan lancé')
              obj.State2=true;
              obj.suiveur
           else
               obj.State2=false;
           end
        end

        function follower(obj)
            preview(obj.cam)
            while 1
                image_camera=getsnapshot(obj.cam);
                %computations...           
                if obj.State2
                else
                    break %my goal is to break this while 1 loop when obj_watcher sends 
                          %an event to obj_linscan99 which leads to: obj.State2=0
                end                
           end
        end 

    end
end
```

Comment: 1) How do you expect the other class to actually send a `notify` if you're stuck in a while loop in this class? 2) Where is handleEvnt? 3) You should really store a handle to the listener object that you create so that you can clean it up properly. In general, the way to flush MATLAB's event queue is `drawnow`.

Comment: 1) My first class ("watcher") is supposed to constantly monitor a parameter, thanks to a while 1 loop. When this parameter reaches a given value, this first class allows my second class (linescan99, described above) to execute its "follower" function (so which also includes a while 1 loop) via an event. I'd like to be able to break this second while 1 loop via my first class, when the parameter "watcher" monitors reaches such another value. 2) In the second class, "follower". 3) Can you please develop?

Comment: I'll comment on the other points when I have more time but how exactly do you expect that addlistener callback to function? Obj refers to the current class not the watcher class. Please post your code from both classes so we have a minimal working example to help you with. Also it seems you didn't take my advise from your last question about reading about the basics of matlab oop.

Comment: @Suever My question is: can I "force" this addlistener to be executed as the ("follower") while 1 loop is executing (adding a line inside this while 1 loop)? My class definitions are now copied in my initial post above. I'm reading them but reading your advice is also very instructive.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. It is now a lot clearer what you are trying to do. The core issue here is that you *cannot* have *both* `linescan99.follower()` and `watcher.follower()` loops running *at the same time* because that would require MATLAB to be multi-threaded. How do you instantiate these two classes and how are you actually trying to call the methods?

Comment: Using the event/listener options, I hoped to be able to implement such a double execution. What would you do? I instantiate these two classes thus: obj_watcher=watcher and obj_linescan99=linescan99(obj_watcher); my initial call is obj_watcher.follower().

Comment: Event/listeners to not allow this execution like this. One way would be to pass your object to be "triggered" to the `follower()` method of the other and explicitly execute it's `follower()` when needed. The better option is to setup a `timer` to execute your commands rather than using a while loop.

Comment: 1) Can you please develop, how you would implement it? 2) Does a timer require a specific time of execution set in advance? My goal would be to execute follower() as long as "data>3" (and I can't predict when and for how long that would be true).

Comment: You can [read the documentation for `timer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer-class.html?refresh=true)

Comment: Don't you know any real multi-threaded option allowing such executions/interactions?

Comment: MATLAB cannot do that. Timers are your best option

Comment: Which language(s) you know could do that?

Comment: Many of them. Try google?

Comment: I don't know how to precisely refer to this type of multi-threading execution: I know Matlab offers some parallel computing options.

Comment: Parallel computing is *not* multi-threading. Computations in each worker are executed independently and there is no messaging between workers in MATLAB parallel computing therefore this is not an application for them.

Comment: Ok! Last point please:
Can you please develop your first suggestion ("One way would be to pass your object to be "triggered" to the follower() method of the other and explicitly execute it's follower() when needed.")?

Comment: I don't have the time/energy to implement it but essentially you would call `linescan99.follower()` *explicitly* from `watcher.follower()` (basically where you currently call `notify`.

Comment: Is there a way to make several Matlab sessions communicate (one able to access to the objects of the other)?

Comment: My code runs faster with the time option than with the "trig" one, indeed. Can you explain to me why?